# While Editing, dates are not being populated in the Editor/Calendar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

Consider a typical **Model-View-Controller** scenario with DB having a few tables, where i provide **CRUD** functionality to my users. For **Updation** scenario, I used to send the required model object to the view, and using `TextBoxFor()` helper method, all the fields used to show the current data values.

Now i used `EditorFor()` helper mehtod, which displayed my *Date fields* as *Calendars*, *integer fields* as *Spinner* and *TextAreas* as *MultiLine Text Editor*.... which is all very good. But the problem is that while presenting the **update** view, my dates are not being populated in the Editor/Calendar. So if the user doesn't want to change the dates, but some other fields only, hitting the **Update Record** button generates the validation errors of *required fields* for all the date fields and the dates have to be entered again which is stupid enough.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

============================

My Model class for summer college is as follows (after deleting non-essential code):

```
// College.cs
[MetadataType(typeof(College_Validation))]
public partial class College {
}
public class College_Validation {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is mandatory")]
    public int CollegeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is mandatory")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

In **Create.cshtml**, inside the `form`...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>College ID: <span class="error">*</span></th>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CollegeID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CollegeID)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Date: <span class="error">*</span></th>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate)</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Got my answer on one of these Questions... Making the following changes to the model solved the problem:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you are doing, so the properties on your classes and their attributes + the code in the view where you render them. I have a hunch that you will need the [DisplayFormat] tag and possibly some culture settings in your web.config, but it's hard to tell from just your explanation.

Comment: I don't wanna use [DisplayFormat] tag. [DataType] seems more thorough as far as I think...

Comment: Problem solved. I've added the answer at the bottom of my question for any future questioners...